# SSLHandshakeException While connecting to https url

Tags: android

I am not that good when it comes to network part in Android. So here I am using POST service. The following code was working fine when URL was using http://  in the prefix. At that time I was using HttpURLConnection API. But the problem occurred when URL served using TLS. I need to use https:// from now on. So I changed HttpURLConnection to HttpsURLConnection in the code. But I don't know why I am getting this exception. [Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReokH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from similar issue..

I have solved by this:

```
public static OkHttpClient getHttpClient() {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
                .cipherSuites(
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
                .build();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
                .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .build();
    }
```

You can try this.